# Animation delay trouble

Tags: html, css

I'm making a loading screen for my website and i want to make a line that goes from 0-100% in few sec. I have made it successfully, but when I try adding animation-delay nothing happens. I want the animation to start 2 sec after the website loads.
Anyone can help?

Here is the code:

```css
.loading
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    display: flex;
    transform: translate(-70px);
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.obj
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 8px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 1; position:relative;
    animation:loading 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes loading{
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 150px;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loadingstyles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loading">
        <div class="obj"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where and how you are adding the delay?

Comment: I tired to add it in .obj but also .loading, non of them worked.

Comment: show us *how*, we see nothing in your code

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: you have a typo, it's `:` not `;`

Comment: Thank you, now should I make it invisible for 2 seconds?

Comment: add with:0 to the element then add `forwards` to the animation

Comment: I have added forwards to the animation but with:0? You want me to change width to 0 in .obj?

Comment: yes, before the animation the width need to be 0 ..and forwards will make it 150px at the end of the animation

Comment: So where should I add or change the width to 0?

Comment: inside .obj ....

Comment: I asked because it was first thing I did before asking here but as you can see it makes the .obj disappear.

Comment: there is no `,` before forwards and you have a missing `}` in the keyframe

Comment: Thank you very much. With your help I have made it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for `transition-delay`. You can add this right into your css. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Comment: I tired transition-delay, doesn't work either. :/